# Индексация поисковыми системами React приложений

Tags: seo, reactjs

Доброго времени суток.

Есть одностраничник, сделанный на React. Однако, веб страница открывается и без JS и содержит всю ту же информацию, как если бы ее открыли с поддержкой JS. Разница лишь в разметке - на React своя, а без React своя совсем простенькая. Вопрос - как такой ресурс будет индексироваться Google and Yandex? Не будет ли претензий со стороный поисковых систем, на различие в верстке?

С одной стороны, если следовать принципу, что веб страница должна в любом случае открываться с поддержкой JS или без и содержать необходимый контент, то вроде ничего страшного.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ничего страшного не будет. 
Ознакомьтесь с рекомендациями ПС ([Яндекс](https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/robot-workings/ajax-indexing.xml) и [Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/81766?hl=ru)). Претензий по верстке у ПС не будет, претензия могла быть по контенту. Поскольку контент отдается (что раньше было проблемой для динамичных сайтов и приложений), то абсолютно никаких проблем не будет.